# Android Get Application Start Up Path

Tags: android, filesystems

In C# there are Application.StartUpPath or Application.AppDataPath global methods to get a path where I would store Application Settings.

I tried `static String fName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "SatCli.conf";`

**"/SatCli.conf"** - is the resulted fName

then I call

```
 BufferedOutputStream oustream = new BufferedOutputStream(new
 FileOutputStream(fName, false));
```

and I am getting the common exception

```
"/SatCli.conf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)"
```

Well, I've been writing apps under Unix and I understand maybe the file name is refering to internal memory.. in other words to the root part of system file system.

Or maybe not.. maybe it refers to the App Folder?

Anyway, what I would like to get is the correct method to get the right folder to store the settings data.
Also, what is important, I need it before any context is built, when static fields are initializing.

Thank you for any relevant hint and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I would like to get is the correct method to get the right folder to store the settings data.

For arbitrary files, call `getFilesDir()` on a `Context` (e.g., `Activity`). This gives you a `File` object representing a private directory where your app can read and write.

FWIW, Android's standard way of storing settings that you collect from the user is `SharedPreferences`, so you can take advantage of `PreferenceFragment` for the UI.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it before, but the context, it takes a value when all static fields and classes are initialized, right? What if I need to get the directory before any context?

Comment: @VitaliPetrov: There is always a context. Create a custom subclass of `Application`. Register it in the `<application>` element via the `android:name` attribute. In `onCreate()` of your `Application` subclass, initialize any `static` fields that require a `Context`.

Comment: I didn't expect that <this> (Pointer to object of a class) is the Context in Android :) Thank you CommonWare